# Delete random objects from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I have an array such as:

```
array=['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
```

I want to delete a random 2 elements. How can I do this?

Comment: without repetitions?

Answer (score 0):

To get two unique items from the array, and if you don't mind mutating the original array, you can use `splice()` to remove the selected item from the array so it won't be picked when you run it a second time:

```
var firstRandomChoice = array.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length), 1);
var secondRandomChoice = array.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length), 1);
```

If you use a utility library such as [lodash](https://lodash.com/), you may already have a function available to do this for you. For example, lodash provides [`sample()`](https://lodash.com/docs#sample). So if you were using lodash, you could just do something like this to get an array of two random items:

```
var results = _.sample(array, 2);
```

Comment: I tried "var results = _.sample(array, 2);" But I can not random 2 objects.It select only one object